# Reading cordinates in objective C for Chipmunk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, chipmunk

I am working on a game in iPhone for which I use the Chipmunk library to generate the environment. So the issue I am facing is that I am calling the coordinates for the obstruction from a file.

I would like some feed back on what's the best way that I store the coordinates of the obstruction for each level either in the form of an XML or an ordinary text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to use a `.plist` file (which is of course XML) for it and then grab them using `NSArray * cArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]`

Answer (score 0):

I would also go with the plist - it simple and easy. If you want something more tied to the code you could go for NSKeyedArchiver. Just make sure all of the classes you want to serialize are NSCoding compliant.